Debian　OSを再起動せず、ネットワーク設定を変更、反映する方法
環境
組み込みCPUボード
OS:debian10
やりたいこと
シェルスクリプトから、設定ファイル/etc/network/interfacesを編集し、IPアドレス等を変更し、動作させながらその内容を反映させいと考えております。
やってみたこと
本質問においては簡潔にするため、物理ポートeth0を事例として挙げておりますが、実際は、eth0,eth1をまとめてブリッジ接続br0とし、br0のIPアドレスを対象としております。
このため、nmcliコマンドでは対応できませんでした。
以下設定ファイルを変更し、サービス再起動させた結果です。
変更前IPアドレスが残った状態で、変更後IPアドレスが追加された状態となりました。
シェルスクリプトからの編集でも、手動の編集でも結果は同じでした。
CPUボードをrebootすると、変更後IPアドレスのみとなり正常に反映されます。
設定変更
/etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 0.0.0.0

変更後
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.6
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 0.0.0.0

サービスの再起動
対象となるサービスnetworking.serviceのリスタートを行ったところ、変更前のIPアドレスが保持されたまま、変更後のIPアドレスが追加されました。
networking.serviceのstatusを見るとFailedが発生しています。
systemctl restart networking.service

# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-11-01 13:46:40 JST; 8min>
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
    Process: 2190 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, stat>
   Main PID: 2190 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 151ms

Nov 01 13:46:40 linaro-alip ifup[2215]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Nov 01 13:46:40 linaro-alip ifup[2190]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Nov 01 13:46:40 linaro-alip systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result >
Nov 01 13:46:40 linaro-alip systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interface

結果表示
ip addr show

...
5: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:bf:b8:c8:9a:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...


質問内に Debianのバージョンを記したほうがよいでしょう (ネットワーク関連のコマンドはそれなり変化していっ
てるので)。手元に Debian無いので動くかどうか不明だけと, ifdown eth0 => /etc/network/interfacesの編集 => ifup eth0 の手順で行うとよいか も


バージョン ... 書いてありますね Debian 10 (buster) , 見落としてました


再起動するサービスは network-manager かもしれません。参考 https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.ja.html

ifdownは機能しません。また、NetoworkManager.serviceのrestartも影響しません。
